# Execution remains ideal for so long while accessing GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Execution seems to ideal and unresponsive while I query from GraphServiceClient (bolded portion). Any guidance will be appreciated

```
private async Task<string> GetUserFullName(string objectIdentifier)
{
    try
    {
        string fullName = string.Empty;
        string[] scopes = { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        **var user = await graphServiceClient.Users[objectIdentifier].Request()
            .Select(u => new
            {
                u.GivenName,
                u.Surname,
                u.Mail
            })
            .GetAsync();**
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullName = user.GivenName + " " + user.Surname + "(" + user.Mail + ")";
        }
        return fullName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it return any result or it just hangs?

Comment: it doesn't return any result... just hangs.. doesn't know what is happening under the hood

Comment: Is there specific documentation or sample that you are following? If so please share. I am able to retrieve properties such as DisplayName, Mail with User.Read scope following this documentation- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=csharp#use-select-to-control-the-properties-returned 

Try configure an actual user OID or UPN [“real-user-oid”] and try testing. 
The code flow also matters. App only authentication cannot access the /me endpoint and would have to call the /users endpoint with the permission User.ReadAll